# Can express mix html and jade routes?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I want to setup an application where I can write as much html over jade as possible. I don't dislike jade, I just want to write html/angular/node APIs, since I'm learning a lot of technologies at once (angular, node, jade, etc).

I would like to build a skeleton project like the following:

1. Static (server built pages using jade or html) for SEO (basic business card pages).
   i.e. sitename.com/about, sitename.com/
2. angular driven admin area (i.e. sitename.com/admin), that is a single html file with embedded  angular views/partials.

Should I just learn jade, or attempt to use this mixed approach?  I have the first part (simple jade static pages).

Comment: +1 because you are not alone ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Express is pretty template-agnostic, in that you can choose any templating engine you like. If you want more HTML-style templates, you could use [ejs](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs) instead of Jade, for instance:

```
// install ejs first
npm install ejs
```

```
// app.js
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { name : 'World' });
});

app.listen(3012);
```

```
// ./views/index.html
<h1>Hello <%= name %>!</h1>
```

```
// Output:
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
```

Comment: thanks, ejs is a much more natural fit for me.  I added ejs-locals for layouts and I'm up and running.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @user376456 +1 for mentioning `ejs-locals`, I always use it when I use `ejs` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can [include html files](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/tree/0.33.0#includes) in jade (now pug). Just write `include path-to-file`